# What are the possible situations that may cause DisconnectNamedPipe to return false and GetLastError() to return 1?

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe, pipeline

I am encounting an error while trying to *disconnect* a pipe in my code using [**DisconnectNamedPipe**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-disconnectnamedpipe):

```
if (this->isPipeClosed()) return true;
if (this->status <= CONNECTING_STATE) return true;
if (!DisconnectNamedPipe(this->instance))
{
   auto err = GetLastError();
   Util::pushKernelLog(TAG, locateHere(), Util::P_ERROR, "DisconnectNamedPipe failed with {}.",
      std::to_string(err).c_str());
   this->status = ERRROR_PIPE_STATE;
   return false;
}
```

The client log:

> [    ERROR][AbstractPipe] DisconnectNamedPipe failed with 1.

At the same time, the pipe server log like this:

[image]

What are the possible situations that may cause **[DisconnectNamedPipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-disconnectnamedpipe)** to return `false` and **GetLastError()** to return `1`?

Comment: When an API fails, you really should NOT call any other code before calling `GetLastError()`, as the error code might get reset before you retrieve it. For instance, how do we know that `locateHere()` doesn't reset the error code if the compiler invokes it first? You should never pass `GetLastError()` as a parameter to other code. Call `GetLastError()` first and save the value to a variable, the use that variable as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau hi, i have corrected the code. But still got the same error.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: are you call `DisconnectNamedPipe` for client end of pipe ? this api must be called only for **server** end of a pipe. if call this for client end will be error - `STATUS_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION` - *The specified handle is not open to the server end of the named pipe.* and this ntstatus conversted to **1** win32 error

Comment: @RbMm Yes, I got it. My purpose is to disconnect the pipeline from the client by DisconnectNamedPipe. So, what should be done to proactively disconnect from the client correctly?

Comment: @wohlstad my fault.

Comment: @RbMm CloseHandle()?

Comment: yes, client must only call `CloseHandle`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sasme thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1329289/what-are-the-possible-situations-that-may-cause-di

GetLastError return 1: `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`, Incorrect function.

According to the Doc: [DisconnectNamedPipe function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-disconnectnamedpipe)

> If the client end of the named pipe is open, the DisconnectNamedPipe
> function forces that end of the named pipe closed. The client receives
> an error the next time it attempts to access the pipe. A client that
> is forced off a pipe by DisconnectNamedPipe must still use the
> CloseHandle function to close its end of the pipe.

As far as I'm concerned, you should try to use `CloseHandle function` to close its end of the pipe.